# How should I implement the HEAD response for a dynamically generated resource?

Tags: http, spring-mvc

Below code is written with Spring MVC. I simulate the `dynamic response generation` by reading a file first and send it to client.

For a `GET` method, the response will contain the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header rather than the `Content-Length` header.

For a `HEAD` method, how should I implement the response? Should I manually insert the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header and remove the `Content-Length` header?

```
@RestController
public class ChunkedTransferAPI {

    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @RequestMapping(value = "xxx.iso", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    public void doChunkedGET(HttpServletResponse response) {

        String filename = "/xxx.iso";
        try {
            ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
            InputStream input = servletContext.getResourceAsStream(filename);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(input);
            int datum = bufferedInput.read();
            while (datum != -1) {
                output.write(datum); //data transfer happens here.
                datum = bufferedInput.read();
            }           
            output.flush();
            output.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "xxx.iso", method = { RequestMethod.HEAD })
    public void doChunkedHEAD(HttpServletResponse response) {       
//      response.setHeader("Server", "Apache-Coyote/1.1");
//      response.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");     
    }   

}
```

My client's behavior is:

1. Initiate a `HEAD` request first to get the `anticipated response size`. This size is used to allocate some buffer.
2. Then initiate a `GET` request to actually get the response content and put it in the buffer.

I kind of have the feeling that I am `catering to` the client's behavior rather than following some RFC standard. I am worried that even if I can make the client happy with my response, it will fail with other servers' responses.

Anyone could shed some light on this? How should I implement the HEAD response?
Or maybe the client should NEVER rely on the HEAD response to decide the size of a GET response because the [RFC](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#HEAD) says:

> The server ***SHOULD*** send the same header fields in response to a HEAD
>   request as it would have sent if the request had been a GET, ***except
>   that the payload header fields*** (Section 3.3) ***MAY be omitted***.

And `Content-Length` happens to be one of the `payload header fields`.

Comment: If you know that you're going to do a GET anyway, why bother with the HEAD request? Why can't you allocate buffers once you need them?

Comment: @JulianReschke I challenged my developer the same way. I really think a HEAD request here is neither necessary nor reliable. But due to some historical design, they have to do it this way.

Comment: Since a file has a known size `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` doesn't make much sense in the first place. There are simpler ways to send a file to the client, btw.